# Cannot write to the partition after copying recovered files in the partition

Tags: windows, hard-drive, filesystem-corruption

About a year ago, I recovered deleted files and saved it in one of the partition in my windows 8 laptop. Now the partition is showing problem. I cannot delete its files and I guess cannot write to it too. I can read the files normally but gives problem while deleting the files from it. Please give me any solutions.

Thank you

Comment: Have you run chkdisk on the problem drive?

Answer (score 0):

i think your partition is in state "WRITE PROTECTED "
now just goto

**STEP 1:** **start**-->search for **cmd** (Right click it to **run as administrator**) or 
 PRESS **WINKEY+R**(opens RUN) and **TYPE CMD** to open command prompt.

**STEP 2:**NOW, TYPE **diskpart** [hit enter]

**STEP 3:** TYPE **LIST VOLUME** (it displays your PARTITION WITH DRIVE LETTERS in your PC)

**STEP 4:** NOW  **SELECT VOLUME 1**(in my case volume no is 1,it may vary for u **else** SELECT VOLUME [DRIVELETTER])
STEP NOW after selecting volume type **DETAIL**(It displays volume details CHECK for READ-ONLY : YES)
THEN 
TYPE a**ttributes volume clear readonly**